# Passing a string from Python to a Bash script using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, unix, subprocess

I have been given bash script that loops through a group of directories and asks for an input (y/n) for each directory.

I am using the Python subprocess module to run the code from Jupyter notebooks and I have

```
def run_shell(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)


    for line in popen.stdout:
        print(line)
        if 'User/Documents' in line:
        
            directory = line.split()[-1]
    
        if 'Do the input' in line:
            print('Inputting')
        
            response = my_function(directory) # response = 'y' or 'n'
        
            inp = popen.communicate(input=response)[0] # option 1 i tried

            popen.stdin.write(response) #expects a bytes type object # option 2 i tried
            popen.communicate()[0]
            popen.stdin.close()
        
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)

run_shell(my_command)
```

The bash script looks something like below:

```
for directory in $directory_list
do
    echo /User/Documents/${directory}
    echo Do the input
    read -p 'Enter y or n ' decision
done
```

Even without trying to give the response through communicate it will never print the 'Enter y or n' line.

The script also calculates the files needed to make the decision so the y and n inputs cant be pre calculated and passed in with input in subprocess.Popen.

Many thanks

Comment: *it will never print the 'Enter y or n' line.* that is the expected behavior, if stdin is not a terminal bash doesn't display the prompt for `read`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `.sh` script and pass arguments to it the following way:

`subprocess.check_output(['sh', './script.sh', arg1, arg2, arg3])`